# Convert differently aligned excel to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel, csv

There will be multiple excel files which has the same fields but they might be aligned differently. Such as in first excel file the "price" column might be at the first sequence but at the 2nd file it might be in the 3rd sequence.

So if I were to ask to user to enter sequences under the name of fields (so I'll know the order of fields), could I only convert those fields in the order that I want to JSON with Javascript or Nodejs? 
If so, how?

***Example:***

***This is client no. 1's data:*** stored in this orientation 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjKXr.jpg

***This is client no. 2's data:*** stored in this orientation. 1 extra data that I won't use and different than the first one.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1DKW.jpg

And I want to parse it exactly as how client no. 1 stored. But there are so many varieties that I'll get. So as I explained above, if I were to get the column numbers of certain fields could I get it in the exact format with first client and transform to JSON like that.

Comment: You should add specific examples/screenshots.

Comment: @jasie Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module excel js for this purpose, it has a lot of nice features.

I've updated to allow passing the column order to the readValues function.

For example:

```
var excel = require('exceljs');
var wb = new excel.Workbook();
var path = require('path');
var client1Path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client1_data.xlsx');
var client2Path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client2_data.xlsx');

function readValues(filePath, columnNumbers) {
    let columnNames = Object.entries(columnNumbers).reduce((a, [key,value]) => {
        a[value] = key;
        return a;
    }, []);

    return wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then( () => {
        var worksheet = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
        var values = [];
        worksheet.eachRow((row) => {
            let obj = row.values.reduce((o, v, index) => {
                if (columnNames[index]) o[columnNames[index]] = v;
                return o;
            }, {});
            values.push(obj);
        });
        return values;
    });
}

async function testReadData() {
    try {
        let client1Data = await readValues(client1Path, { price: 1, name: 2, country: 3});
        console.log('testReadData: Client 1 data: ', client1Data);
        let client2Data = await readValues(client2Path, { price: 2, name: 1, country: 4});
        console.log('testReadData: Client 2 data: ', client2Data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('testReadData: Error occurred: ', error);
    }
}

testReadData();
```

I'm using the same data as in your examples (now corrected).

e.g.

Client 1 data:

```
$50 Jack    USA
$30 Harold  USA
```

Client 2 data:

```
Jack    $50 Florida USA
Harold  $30 California  USA
```

The output will be like:

testReadData: Client 1 data:

```
[ { price: '$50', name: 'Jack', country: 'USA' },
{ price: '$30', name: 'Harold', country: 'USA' } ]
```

testReadData: Client 2 data:

```
[ { name: 'Jack', price: '$50', country: 'USA' },
{ name: 'Harold', price: '$30', country: 'USA' } ]
```

Comment: That's very useful thanks, but I updated the question for better understanding. Could you also cover the question that I've asked?

Comment: Sure, will do that!!